# The Liitle Schemer 4th page81 rember* function

Tags: scheme

I'm studying The Liitle Schemer 4th.

Sometimes I have a different solution. It confuses me and I can't easily understand the standard answer of the book.

For example, with  rember*:

My solution is :

```
   (define rember*
     (lambda (a l)
       (cond
        ((null? l) '())
        ((atom? l) l)
        ((eq? a (car l)) (rember* a (cdr l)))
        (else (cons (rember* a (car l)) (rember* a (cdr l)))))))
```

The book's solution:

```
(define rember*
  (lambda (a l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) '())
      ((atom? (car l))
       (cond
         ((eq? (car l) a)
          (rember* a (cdr l)))
         (else (cons (car l)
                 (rember* a (car l))))))
      (else (cons (rember* a (car l))
               (rember* a (cdr l)))))))
```

Which is better?

One more question.

Original structure:

```
(define rember*
  (lambda (a l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) '())
      ((atom? (car l))
       (cond
         ((eq? (car l) a)
          (rember* a (cdr l)))
         (else (cons (car l)
                 (rember* a (car l))))))
      (else (cons (rember* a (car l))
               (rember* a (cdr l)))))))
```

New structrue:

```
(define rember*
  (lambda (a l)
    (cond
     ((null? l) '())
     ((atom? (car l)) (cond
                       ((eq? (car l) a) (rember* a (cdr l)))
                       (else (cons (car l) (rember* a (cdr l))))))
     (else (cons (rember* a (car l)) (rember* a (cdr l)))))))
```

Which is better for everyone?

Comment: The second question is a matter of taste and off topic in SO. Both are according to lisp style. I would have used the second in this case, but reverted to the first if the code gets wider. In the first case I usually add an empty line between terms that are multi line just to increase readability. I would have reverted to `if` for the inner `cond` since it doesn't use any distinct features of `cond` over `if`.

Comment: OK I got it. <3 <3 <3 Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, is not unusual that the same function is implemented by different programs. In your example, however, the two programs implement different functions, so that I think is not immediate to say “which is the best”.

The second program (that of the book), implements a function defined over the domain of the lists, and *only* that domain. So, you cannot give to it an atom, for instance, since it would produce an error.

The first one (your version), on the other hand, can be applied to lists (and in this case has the same behaviour of the second one), but can be applied also to atoms, so that you can do, for instance:

```
(rember* 'a 'a)  ; returns a
(rember* 'a 'b)  ; returns b
```

So, one should look at the specification of the function, and see if a program implements in a consistent way this specification. I would say that the first program in not entirely consistent with the specification of the function (remove an element from the second argument), but this is just an opinion, since the function is well defined only over the domain of the lists.